# Repeating push messages for old messages from months ago

Tags: android, ios, erlang, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd community 14.05 and MongoDB version 2.2.4 to power the backend of a cross platform instant messaging app that is available on Android and IOS.

Unfortunately, users are complaining that they are intermittently getting repeat push messages of previously received and read old messages from many months ago on the ios version of the chat app. This occurs when the internet connection is weak or changes from 3g to Wi-Fi.

These push messages are not generated by the app. We are using xep-198. The problem is we have seen this issue occurring but cannot repeat it on a consistent basis. Based on my understanding of ejabberd it is theoretically impossible for push messages of old messages to be redelivered.

Anyone have any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: What push message are you talking about ? ejabberd Community edition does not offer a push module, so it is unclear what you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, Mickael is correct.I should have said that that very old read messages are received by the eJ offline_message_hook, generating the repeating push notifications I mentioned earlier. Has anyone experienced this and know why it could be happening?

Comment: No idea. You probably have bugs in the code you are using, but it does not seems to be standard ejabberd, so hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: Did you found what your issue was ?